Install Ubuntu 24.04 via WSL in windows 10 from .iso file in a specific folder
I'm planning to install Ubuntu 24.04 via WSL on windows 10. the .iso file for ubuntu is already downloaded. Is there a way to have WSL use this image for installation?
At the same time, I'd like to install Ubuntu in a different partition rather than the windows' partition, but I was not able to find anything in "wsl --help" as to this matter. I'd appreciate any help.

I can offer you a way to create the Ubuntu distribution directly on a different drive, but the easier way is to first install to the default location and then move it to the desired drive. Is that okay? The "install directly to another drive" option is much more complex.

@NotTheDr01ds yes, the alternative is alright, I'd appreciate it. however, please explain the outline for the direct installation if possible.


Is there a way to have WSL use this image for installation?

No. The Ubuntu ISO is designed to boot a physical or virtual machine with real hardware interfaces (BIOS/UEFI, bootloaders, ACPI/PowerOn/PowerOff, ports, etc.). Ubuntu on WSL is not running as a virtual machine, but rather as a container. For that reason, the installation process is much more like Docker, where a root filesystem is imported into WSL.

I'd like to install Ubuntu in a different partition rather than the windows' partition

Given our comments discussion, there are a few methods.
The "Very-easy, Pre-release" way
Very fortuitous timing - Apparently, Microsoft just added this feature to a pre-release version of WSL.  Pre-release versions of WSL are usually pretty stable, and you can always return to the stable version if you have issues (after using this feature to move the distribution).

Launch PowerShell as your normal (non-Admin) user

Since it sounds like you already have WSL installed, update to pre-release using:
wsl --update --pre-release


Install Ubuntu 24.04 to its normal location. While you can do this from the Microsoft Store, we're going to need PowerShell for the rest of these steps anyway, so just run the commandline installer:
wsl --install Ubuntu-24.04
# or (slower, but if needed)
wsl --install --web-download Ubuntu-24.04


Create your username and password; Ubuntu will launch automatically

Exit the shell (Ctrl+D or exit)

Shutdown WSL so that no files are in use:
wsl --shutdown


Create the target directory (e.g., D:\WSL\Ubuntu-24.04)

Use the new wsl --manage --move command:
wsl --manage Ubuntu-24.04 --move D:\WSL\Ubuntu-24.04



The "Pretty-easy, Pretty-hacky" way
See this Super User answer. I've done this is the past and can confirm it works.  It's essentially what the --manage --move option above does anyway.
The "Old-reliable way"
Included for completeness, but the recommended way to move, prior to the --manage --move option, was:

Install Ubuntu
wsl --export the image
wsl --import the image to the new location with a new distribution name
Set the default username
Unregister the distribution from the original location

The "If you must ..." way
As mentioned in the comments, it's possible to install directly to a different drive, but it's not easy. Summary as requested:

Obtain the rootfs for Ubuntu 24.04 - There are several ways of doing this, but perhaps the easiest is to download the appx directly and extract the install.tar.gz (rootfs) from inside it.
wsl --import the rootfs
Run the distribution
Create your default user with the proper permissions (e.g., groups of ntd adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev users netdev on Ubuntu 24.04)
Set the default username


Just as an update to NotTheDr01ds’ answer:
Their first approach using the wsl --manage <distribution> --move <location>
now seems to be working without having to update to pre-release
(works on WSL version 2.3.26.0 as of date of writing this answer).
Moved Ubuntu (Microsoft store app) successfully to new location
with another drive letter. 
Seems to have only really just moved the image file (.vhdx),
but that's the largest file anyway.
